# Class mix up for [nav visibleViewController]

Tags: ios, class, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have implemented a sort of settings panel with the SWRevealViewController and I am trying to communicate to one of two VCs that access it

The navigational path for VC2 requires a segue from VC1

```
UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController*)[self.revealViewController frontViewController];
UINavigationController *nav = [[tabBar viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Being sent to a %@",NSStringFromClass([[nav visibleViewController] class]));
if([[nav visibleViewController] isKindOfClass:[VC1 class]]){
    VC1 *view = (VC1 *)[[nav viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    [view setUrlString:typeOfSearch];
    [view startSearchOver];
}else if( [[nav visibleViewController] isKindOfClass:[VC2 class]]){
    VC2 *view = (VC2 *)[[nav viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    [view setUrlString:typeOfSearch];
    [view refreshRequest];
}
```

I am trying to communicate to VC2. When the VC class is being tested, the console prints out VC2, however when I run [VC2 refreshRequest] the app crashes and this is what I see in the console.

```
[VC1 refreshRequest]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x175b4a20
```

I've already decided to work around this with NSUserDefaults, so I am merely asking for piece of mind. Why is this happening?

Edit: I'm a moron lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is asking for trouble:

```
if([[nav visibleViewController] isKindOfClass:[VC1 class]]){
    VC1 *view = (EventSearchView *)[[nav viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```

It tests to see if `[nav visibleViewController]` is a VC1, then, ignoring what it just learned, it casts some other object `[[nav viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]` as some other type (`EventSearchView`).  So there are two mistakes: (1) testing one object and casting another, and (2) testing an object to be of TypeA, but then casting as TypeB.

We know nothing about the class of that second object inside the conditional. With the crash at run time, we learn that it isn't what we think it is.

The safe pattern for type introspection is this:

```
id instanceOfUnknownClass = // whatever
if ([instanceOfUnknownClass isKindOfClass:[SomeClass self]]) {
    SomeClass *nowWeKnow = (SomeClass *) instanceOfUnknownClass;
    // safely message nowWeKnow according to SomeClass's interface
}
```

Notice how we cast the object who's type we tested and that we cast it to the type that it was tested to be.

Comment: Sorry, I've just fixed the typo, those are the names of VC1 and VC2 lol

Comment: @Jargen89 - that fixes one of the two problems, but the code still tests one object and casts another.